# How do I authenticate an LTI grade return?

Tags: desire2learn, lti

I have an external tool which I connected to my D2L site through LTI. When a student completes his work, I want the tool to send the grade back to the LMS.
I receive a "Not authenticated" message from D2L when sending the grade with the XML payload. How do I authenticate my grade posting?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication required is down to how it must be done as described in the [LTI 1.1 implementation guide](http://www.imsglobal.org/LTI/v1p1/ltiIMGv1p1.html). In particular (from LTI 1.1 impl guide), pay attention to section [4: LTI Security Model](http://www.imsglobal.org/LTI/v1p1/ltiIMGv1p1.html#_Toc319560466) and section [6.1: LTI Basic Outcome Service](http://www.imsglobal.org/LTI/v1p1/ltiIMGv1p1.html#_Toc319560472).

Quick summary of requirements, I believe (as per section [4.3: Security for application/xml Messages](http://www.imsglobal.org/LTI/v1p1/ltiIMGv1p1.html#_Toc319560469)):

- form up the POX (plain 'ol XML) body
- calculate the body hash value
- set the `oauth_body_hash` parm to this value
- sign the request as per Oauth signing rules, and note that the `oauth_body_hash` *must* be included in the base string to sign together with the other request parms
- transmit the `oauth_body_has`h parm along with the OAuth parms in the signed request

D2L *highly* recommends that implementors use a reliable OAuth standard library for their particular platform to do the signature generation and verification, rather than attempt to implement the OAuth signing/verification algorithm on their own.

Note that the Oauth parms in this case get transmitted in the request *header* and not in the body data. The IMS spec itself contains an example of what the body should look like ([sec 4.3](http://www.imsglobal.org/LTI/v1p1/ltiIMGv1p1.html#_Toc319560469)):

```
POST http://www.imsglobal.org/developers/BLTI/service_handle.php HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:80
Content-Length: 757
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_version="1.0",
  oauth_nonce="29f90c047a44b2ece73d00a09364d49b",
  oauth_timestamp="1313350943",oauth_consumer_key="lmsng.school.edu",
  oauth_body_hash="v%2BxFnmDSHV%2Fj29qhxLwkFILrtPo%3D",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_signature="8auRpRdPY2KRXUrOyz3HKCs92y8%3D"
Content-type: application/xml

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<imsx_POXEnvelopeRequest xmlns = "http://www.imsglobal.org/services/ltiv1p1/xsd/imsoms_v1p0">  
  <imsx_POXHeader>    
    <imsx_POXRequestHeaderInfo>     
      <imsx_version>V1.0</imsx_version>
      <imsx_messageIdentifier>999999123</imsx_messageIdentifier>    
    </imsx_POXRequestHeaderInfo>  
  </imsx_POXHeader>  
  <imsx_POXBody>    
    <readResultRequest>     
      <resultRecord>
        <sourcedGUID>
          <sourcedId>3124567</sourcedId>
        </sourcedGUID>
      </resultRecord>   
    </readResultRequest>  
  </imsx_POXBody> 
</imsx_POXEnvelopeRequest>
```